# Drag and lift as a function of speed

Tags: classical-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics, aircraft, lift

Assuming turbulent flow, the drag force $F_\mathrm d$ and the lift force $F_\mathrm l$ are usually given in terms of the following equations
$$ F_d\, =\, \tfrac12\, \rho\, u^2\, c_d\, A $$

$$ F_l\, =\, \tfrac12\, \rho\, u^2\, c_l\, A $$
where
$\rho$ is the mass density, 
$u$ is the speed of the object, and
$A$ is the characteristic area of the airfoil.
Here, $c_\mathrm d$ and $c_\mathrm l$ are respectively the drag and lift coefficients of the airfoil.

The coefficients $c_\mathrm d$ and $c_\mathrm l$ depend in general on the shape of the airfoil, on the angle of attach, but also on the Reynolds number, and as a consequence, they depend indirectly on the speed $u$. 
Therefore, the functional dependence of the drag and lift forces on the speed $u$ can be in principle more complicated than the equations above.

My question is:
Are there experimental measurements of the drag and lift coefficients $c_\mathrm d$ and $c_\mathrm l$ as a function of the speed $u$, or alternatively, experimental measurements of the drag $F_\mathrm d$ and the lift force $F_\mathrm l$ as a function of $u$?

Comment: You could do a web search on ballistic coefficients.  I came across an unclassified government white paper that had such models and data for some objects.  Not airfoils for planes but it's something.

Comment: I think ballistic coefficients refers to a different kind of regime. In my understanding the lift force on a bullet is zero or negligible. In any case, could you post here the link to the white paper you found?